# How to Create One to Many Relationships From JSON with Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to create one to many relationships from JSON items in a file. Specifically, each JSON item contains an author and the id of books they have published. I have author nodes and book nodes that already exist in the database.

The data looks like:

```
{"id": "1", "name": "Dr. Suess", "books": [{"i": "100", "i": "101"}]}
{"id": "2", "name": "Shell Silverstein", "books": [{"i": "200", "i": "201"}]}
```

I am trying to import the nodes with the following code:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:/data.txt') YIELD value AS q 
    MATCH (a:Author {{id:q.id}})
    UNWIND q.books as books
    WITH a, books
    MATCH (b:Books {{id:books.i}})
    CREATE (a)-[:AUTHORED]->(b)
```

However, this is importing a fraction of the nodes I am expecting. Any suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well if you say that not all the authors and books are imported it means that the two `MATCH` statements don't find what they are looking for.

One possible scenario is that you have the IDs stored as an integer, but now you are trying to match them as a string. With the provided information, it is hard to assume anything else.

I would change the `MATCH` into `MERGE` statements to see if that is the problem.

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:/data.txt') YIELD value AS q 
    MERGE (a:Author {{id:q.id}})
    UNWIND q.books as books
    WITH a, books
    MERGE (b:Books {{id:books.i}})
    CREATE (a)-[:AUTHORED]->(b)
```